# Lagragian floer homology vs homology of $\Omega(L_0,L_1)$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology

I'm very new to this subject, so apologies for a very naive question and probably many mistakes. Let $M$ be some compact sympletic manifold with $L_0,L_1$ Lagrangian submanifolds which intersects transversely. My understanding if that the Lagrangian Floer homology $HF^*(L_0,L_1)$ is some sort of imitation of Morse theory on the space $\Omega(L_0,L_1)$ which is the space of paths out of $[0,1]$ whose endpoints go from $L_0$ to $L_1$. It seems to me a natural question to ask if how this resulting chain complex (I always quotient out by quasi-isomorphisms) $HF^*(L_0,L_1)$ is related to the singular chains on the space $\Omega(L_0,L_1)$ which I would think of as the chain complex associated to the space/homotopy type of $\Omega(L_0,L_1)$. Are they the same under some nice assumptions?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but note that Floer cohomology is trying to get at the semiinfinite dimensional cohomology (i.e. the Hessian of the Morse function has infinitely many positive and infinitely many negative eigenvalues) rather than the usual cohomology.

Comment: Note also that if L_0 and L_1 are cotangent fibres in a cotangent bundle (say at x and y) then the wrapped HF recovers the ordinary cohomology of the path space between x and y in the base, not in the cotangent bundle.

Comment: @Jonny Evans, Is the cohomology of the path space in the cotangent bundle different than that of the path space in the base?  The cotangent bundle with the fibres deformation  retracts to the base, so it seems natural to guess that the path spaces will be homotopy equivalent.  It is not the case?

Comment: Doh! You're right, Yaniv. But I think this poorly chosen example of mine is just coincidence. The fibration which projects paths between cotangent fibres to paths in the base collapses an infinite-dimensional contractible space, and Morse index is not going to be well behaved under such operations. Maybe this is why the semiinfinite cohomology turns out to compute the ordinary cohomology of something else in this case, and this just happens to be homotopy equivalent to what you started with.